# When to apply complex integration for integral resolutions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, soft-question, contour-integration

> Is there a criterion, a clue that makes me think that certain integrals can also be solved through complex integration and how to solve them?

---

When I can't solve an integral for my students of a high school, I use the numerical methods.

If I have these integrals how are they solved used the complex integrations?

**First integral**: $${\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}}\dfrac1{2\cos\left(x\right)+5}\,\mathrm{d}x={\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}}\dfrac{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}2\right)}{3\tan^2\left(\frac{x}2\right)+7}\,\mathrm{d}x \tag 1$$
I remember that $-2\leq 2\cos x\leq 2 \to 0<3\leq 2\cos x+5\leq 7$. Hence $2\cos x+5\neq 0, \forall x\in\Bbb R$.

Using the substitution $t=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}\tan\left(\frac{x}2\right)}{\sqrt{7}}$
I will have

$$\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{2\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}\sec^2\left(\frac{x}2\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Starting from the $(1)$ I will have $$(1)={\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}}\dfrac{2\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}\left(7t^2+7\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

and with easy steps I have:

$$=\left[\dfrac{2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\tan\left(\frac{x}2\right)}{\sqrt{7}}\right)}{\sqrt{21}}\right]_0^{2\pi}=\dfrac{2{\pi}}{\sqrt{21}}$$

**Second integral**: remember that $(x^2+1)^2\ne 0, \forall x\in\Bbb R$.
$$\displaystyle\int\limits^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$
Apply reduction formula:
$$\small{{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac1{\left(\mathtt{a}x^2+\mathtt{b}\right)^{\mathtt{n}}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{2\mathtt{n}-3}{2\mathtt{b}\left(\mathtt{n}-1\right)}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac1{\left(\mathtt{a}x^2+\mathtt{b}\right)^{\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\mathtt{n}-1}}}}\,\mathrm{d}x+\dfrac{x}{2\mathtt{b}\left(\mathtt{n}-1\right)\left(\mathtt{a}x^2+\mathtt{b}\right)^{\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-3}{\mathtt{n}-1}}}}}$$

I have:

$$\begin{aligned}&=\dfrac{x}{2\left(x^2+1\right)}+\dfrac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac1{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=\lim_{p\to+\infty}\left[\dfrac{\arctan\left(x\right)}2+\dfrac{x}{2\left(x^2+1\right)}\right]_{-p}^p=\frac \pi2\end{aligned}$$

**Third example**: Obviously it must be $\sqrt{x}\left(x+1\right) \neq 0 \iff x>0$

$${\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}}\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}\left(x+1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

If I take $t=\sqrt{x} \to \mathrm{d}x=2\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{d}t$. When with simple steps I will find

$$=\lim_{p\to+\infty}\left[2\arctan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right]_0^p=\pi$$

Thank you all very much and I hope always the best for all users.

Comment: when you've got an integral over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^+$, and the integrand is a composition of standard functions such as exponentials and rational functions, you can certainly try it

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I have not done complex analysis, if you can if you and the other users welcome for your answer.

Comment: What is the reason of two downvotes for my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your post would be more well received if you put some examples of integrals you'd solved so far using the numerical methods or other problems you've encountered to clarify the exact problem. From my perspective, as I was a high-school student until recently, I would like to compare some of the tasks we did. You see, that way it would be more useful to future beginner readers. Have a nice day and (+1) for an interesting question. Very few high-school teachers try to improve themselves day by day.

Comment: @Croissant I have answered you to the first part of your kind comment that I really have appreciated. Now I have added a resolution of a defined integral hoping that my question will not be closed again having already 4 requests for closure.

Comment: @Croissant I thank you immensely for your kindness and positive vote but as I always write on TeX.SE. I'm not interested in votes but rather in receiving answers to increase my knowledge. I consider myself a modest and humble high school teacher who always tries to do the best for the students. But unfortunately after 21 years in the Italian school world I realize that many people prefer to remain ignorant and take only the salary money.

Comment: @Croissant I thank you immensely for your kindness and positive vote but as I always write on TeX.SE. I'm not interested in votes but rather in receiving answers to increase my knowledge. I consider myself a modest and humble high school teacher who always tries to do the best for the students.

Comment: @Croissant But unfortunately after 21 years in the Italian school world I realize that many people prefer to remain ignorant and take only the salary money. I guarantee you that like me he works with seriousness and humility is not gratified. On the contrary, he is denigrated and humiliated for the envy of his colleagues, parents who want and expect high votes for their sons and daughters who are not adequate and for personal interests that have no connection with the public good.

Comment: Sebastiano, I think I get your point. In fact, I think you might like [this site](http://halapa.com/) for high-school students and teachers. There are plenty of tasks, each day the number increases. The professor founder's iniciative was to "collect" knowledge appropriate for the high-school students, and more, for the curious ones. I like taking part in that adventure as much as the students all around the world! Feel free to share problems/solutions (if you want). I'm leaving the link here as a source of many other examples that are yet to come! Unfortunately, my colleagues do it secretly.

Comment: Due to the jealousy and everything you counted. [here, no. 29, integrals](http://www.halapa.com/matos.htm) - for various levels.

Comment: @Croissant Thank you with all my heart.

Comment: Sebastiano, thank you for your contributions and never underestimate your work. It does bring fruit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestive principle is this.  To evaluate the integral $\int_a^b f(x)\;dx$ by complex contour integral methods, it is (usually) required that $a$ and $b$ are "special" points for the function $f$:  for example, poles or branch points.

For example,
$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\tag1$$
is a good candidate, since $\pm1$ are branch points for the integrand.  But
$$
\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\tag2$$
is not a good candidate, since the point $x=1/2$ is nothing special for that integrand.  Probably evaluating $(2)$ is no easier than evaluating the indefinite integral
$$
\int_{a}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\tag2
$$
for all $a$ with $-1 < a < 1$.